# ASP.NET showing development machine folders on exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, compilation, web-config

I have a project in ASP.NET, after i finished it i did the following steps before moving to production server:

set compile: release

web.config
compilation debug="false"

after this i made a clean and build on project and published files with copy paste method.

but even with this, when an unhandled exception occurs it shows the folders of my development machine where i worked the project.

is there something else im missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set customErrors mode to remoteOnly to prevent showing exception details when error occurs for remote accessing users.

Check this msdn page for more info

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: i also saw in the compilation settings of the project, some trace options, i will turn them off.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like IIS directory browsing feature is turned on?  Try checking out and disabling [the setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  If that is not what you are referring, please edit your question to provide additional details.